# Laravel force prefix

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

In my app I provided prefix e.g. `en` which my site loads as `domain.xyz/en` now this is working, but what I need to add is:

> force redirect when user visits websites without any prefix:

e.g. user try to load `domain.xyz` this domain must redirect to `domain.xyz/en` (**default prefix**) for the first time in order to site loads, but later if user choose another lang it can be set to that. r.g. `domain.xyz/es`

#### Question

What should I write in my middleware to achieve that redirect?

I've tried to use:

```
1-$request->route().parameters();
and
2-$request->route().getPrefix();
```

no luck.

`code`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class PrefixMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

## Update

Here is how my `web.php` looks like:

```
$route_prefix = \Config::get('app.route_prefix');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'verified', 'prefix' =>  $route_prefix.'/'], function () use ($route_prefix){
  Route::get('/', 'HomeController@welcome')->name('homepage');
});
```

## Update 2

Based on comments suggestion now I have something like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $prefix = \Config::get('app.route_prefix');
        \App::setLocale($prefix);
        return $next($request.'/'.$prefix);
    }
```

and it returns:

```
Call to a member function setUserResolver() on string
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization#configuring-the-locale

Comment: @LimKeanPhang my `web.php` file `Route::group(['middleware' => 'verified', 'prefix' =>  $route_prefix.'/'], function () use ($route_prefix){`

Comment: Add this before in middleware before return \App::setLocale(\'en')); ? Add use App; as well

Comment: @LimKeanPhang updated my question

Comment: That's another problem or what because i dont see setUserResolver on your provided code~ @@ Try check your overall program code again.

Comment: I dont really think you need the prefix to set the default language on first visit thou. Just middleware will do..Hmm.

Comment: @LimKeanPhang middleware will change the lang but won't all prefix to the url's so i need to provide prefix in my groups that's why. (it's bad for seo)

Comment: I was providing half of the solution only. My approach was set on session and middleware will always pick up the session key until user changed it. See if you get what i mean :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I used [this tutorial](https://tjd-studio.com/blog/how-to-use-language-slug-in-laravel-url-and-set-directions) and it fixed my problem